# Material Design Lite grid not adapting on mobiles

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm creating a design update for my website, I beginned with bootstrap and did this : http://lmprepa.fr/beta/index.html

 Then I discovered Material Design Lite and restarted all with this.

 I did this : http://lmprepa.fr/beta/index-new.html

The grid works well on desktop, when you resize the window it adapts, nevertheless, when you go on the website on mobile, it is displayed like when you are on a wide screen

My code is :

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
<div class="mdl-grid chap-container">
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Sommations</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Logique, ensembles et applications</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Fonctions usuelles</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Nombres complexes</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Calcul de primitives et d'intégrales</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Equations différentielle linéaires</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Entiers naturels et ensembles finis</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Ensembles ordonnés et réels</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Suites réelles et complexes</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Limites</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Continuité</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Dérivabilité</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Espaces vectoriels</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Intégration</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Espaces vectoriels de dimension finie</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Géométrie plane</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col chap-link" href="index_new.html">
        <div class="mdl-grid chap">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
                <strong>Arcs paramétrés</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="chap-icons mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
                <i class="material-icons  chap-icon">class</i>
                <i class="material-icons chap-icon">format_list_bulleted</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>


</div>
<h1>LMPrépa, qu'est-ce que c'est ?</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, i forget du write in the header :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I added it and it solved all my layout problems

Thank you for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mdl-layout--small-screen-only` to display what you want in a small screen then `mdl-layout--large-screen-only` for what you want visible in a large screen layout. quite tedious but you can get to display what you want in what screen.

Also for each `mdl-cell` in your anchors, add a `mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone` with column values you want to appear in small screens.